# UIPageViewController deallocating first view controller after moving to the third?

Tags: ios, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using UIPageViewController to display 3 viewcontrollers. If I move to the third and then go back to the first view controller, the first view controller is deallocated from memory. How can I fix this while still using UIPageViewController or is it just not the intended use of UIPageViewController?

Comment: you must share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a strong reference to the `UIViewController`'s either with an array, or individually in your `UIPageViewController`. Note that when the device runs low on memory, the controllers will unload their views.

**Swift:**

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]?
    // or
    var viewControllerA: UIViewController?
    var viewControllerB: UIViewController?
    var viewControllerC: UIViewController?
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
@interface PageViewController: UIPageViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* viewControllers;
// or
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* viewControllerA;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* viewControllerB;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* viewControllerC;

@end
```

Comment: Good point, I do that but it still hides them on each side :/  https://stackoverflow.com/q/76055638/294884